# Abstract property behaviour using interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have an ITiming interface:

```
public interface ITiming
{
    DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And a few classes that implement it:

```
public class Post : ITiming
{
    public int IdPost { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

In my model builder I'm setting the `AfterSaveBehavior` for each entity that implements ITiming, like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.IdPost);

    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt)
        .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
});
```

How can I abstract the AfterSaveBehaviour for all entities CreatedAt columns that implement ITiming?

```
            // not sure about this
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                if (typeof(ITiming).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
                {
                    ??
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use [`FindProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableentitytype.findproperty?view=efcore-2.1) to get access to the property mutable metadata:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    if (typeof(ITiming).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
    {
        entityType.FindProperty(nameof(ITiming.CreatedAt))
            .AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could ignore the interface and apply a custom `DateTime CreatedAt` property convention:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) && p.Name == "CreatedAt"))
{
    property.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
}
```